# Unable to installed .net framework 4.0 in win7

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

when i try to install .Net Framework. i am getting following error. also i have run it as "Administrator"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE1sM.png)

how to solve it?

Comment: Don't put up pictures on external sites to describe a problem.

Comment: need 10 rep to post image here

Comment: I wonder why the error message "_Unable to create or save new files in the folder into which the files are being extracted. Please check the folder properties to ensure you have permission on the folder to write files and that the folder is not read only_" is so verbose ... "_permission to write_" and "_not read only_" sound like the same thing??

Answer (score 0):

Copy your installer to a public directory such as Downloads or My Documents. The issue is the installer is not able to extract its own files due to access issues or space issues. Also check event viewer for more info or error.